# Getting run time error in Visual studio 2013- No Symbol loaded error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, runtime-error, pdb-files

I have tried multiple way to resolve this issue, but not able to resolve this issue please help me to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the default settings in VS2013 changed slightly (from what I can tell anyway). Go into Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. Scroll down and uncheck "Warn if no symbols on launch (Native only)". That should stop the message from appearing.